# VBA UserForm in Excel--mismatched rows on spreadsheet data entry

Tags: forms, vba, excel, listbox

I have a userform created via VBA that is supposed to populate rows on an Excel sheet. It does, but they're one off:

```
Name   |   Race   |   Agency
           Black
Joe        Asian      B
           White
Joanne                C
```

Joe's races are black and Asian, at agency B; Joanne's is white, and she's at agency C. Somehow, the entries are staggered.

Name is a textbox, race and agency are listboxes, with race as a multiselect and agency as a single select.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Integer
With ListBox2
ReDim arr(.ListCount - 1)
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) = True Then
        .Selected(i) = False
        arr(j) = .List(i)
        j = j + i
        End If
    Next i
End With
ReDim Preserve arr(j)
With ActiveSheet
.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp). _
Offset(1, 0).Resize(j + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
End With
i = 1
While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value <> ""
i = i + 1
Wend
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = TextBox1.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value = ListBox1.Value
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctl)
        Case "TextBox"
            ctl.Text = ""
        Case "CheckBox", "OptionButton", "ToggleButton"
            ctl.Value = False
        Case "ComboBox", "ListBox"
            ctl.ListIndex = -1
    End Select
Next ctl
End Sub
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ListBox1.List = Array("A", "B", "C")
With ListBox2
  .Clear
  .AddItem "White"
  .AddItem "Black"
  .AddItem "Asian"
  .AddItem "Am Indian/Al Native"
  .AddItem "Native Hawaiian/Pac Islander"
  .AddItem "Other"
End With
End Sub
```

I would love any ideas ya'll have on how to fix that! Ideally, it would come out in one of the following ways:

```
Name   |   Race   |   Agency
Joe        Black      B
           Asian      B
Joanne     White      C
```

or

```
Name   |   Race          |   Agency
Joe        Black, Asian      B
Joanne     White             C
```

or

```
Name   |   Race   |   Agency
Joe        Black      B
Joe        Asian      B
Joanne     White      C
```

(I prefer the second, but any would work.)

Comment: have you tried actually debugging the code line-by-line to see *why* it spits out the results its does and then tried to fix it yourself? Or do you expect us to do that for you? If the latter, you may not receive much help. If the former, narrow down your question to what you cannot get to work and you will have more willing help.

Comment: The code runs with no error messages...it just comes out wonky in the sheet. I've tried going through it line by line myself and tweaking things and Googling possible solutions, but it's not coming out right. Is there another type of debugging I can do?

Comment: Try adding `i = i - 1` just after the line `Wend`

Comment: You say "Joe's races are black and Asian, at agency B; Joanne's is white, and she's at agency C" - are you sure that isn't meant to be "Joe's race is black, at agency B; Joanne's races are Asian and white, and she's at agency C"?  Your code specifically places the names and agencies one row below the last race.

Comment: @ShannonC - Fair enough. Is one name entered at a time (on a click, I mean)?

Comment: @YowE3K, I think you're right--my apologies!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, yes, on a command button click.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the code appropriately, the refactored `CommandButton1_Click` procedure below should produce the preferred result for you.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim j As Long
Dim i As Integer

'load races into array
With ListBox2

    ReDim arr(.ListCount - 1)

    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1

        If .Selected(i) = True Then
            .Selected(i) = False
            arr(j) = .List(i)
            j = j + i
        End If

    Next i

End With

ReDim Preserve arr(j)

'build "," separated string of races
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

    Dim sRace As String
    sRace = sRace & "," & arr(i)

Next
sRace = Mid(sRace, 2) 'to remove first comma

'place info on next available line in sheet.
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    .Range("A" & lRow).Value = TextBox1.Value
    .Range("B" & lRow).Value = sRace
    .Range("C" & lRow).Value = ListBox1.Value

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of looping through `arr` to concatenate the selected entries, you could do a Join: `sRace = Join(arr, ", ")`, or alternately concatenate it to begin with on your loop through ListBox2 so you don't have to repeat work.

Comment: just to throw some really tiny details 1) you can use `If .Selected(i) Then` 2) you can avoid `ReDim Preserve arr(j)` and loop `For i = LBound(arr) To j-1`